# Where should I put my DECLSPEC for a namespace?

Tags: c++

given the following namespace, where do I put my declspec (for dll export) i I want all the methods in said namespace to be exported into the DLL?

```
namespace AguiText {
    void drawTextArea(AguiGraphicsManager *g, const AguiFont &font,const AguiRectangle &area,
        const AguiColor &color, const std::vector<std::string> &lines,
        AguiHorizontalAlignmentEnum horizontalAlignment, AguiVerticalAlignmentEnum verticalAlignment);

    void divideText(std::vector<std::string> &words, 
        const std::string &text,const AguiFont &font, int maxWidth = -1);
    void makeTextLines(const AguiFont &font,const std::vector<std::string> &words,
        std::vector<std::string> &lineWords, int maxWidth );
    void pointInTextArea(const AguiFont &font, 
        const AguiRectangle &area, const AguiPoint &point, 
        const std::vector<std::string> &lines, AguiRectangle &retRect,
        int &retIndex, AguiHorizontalAlignmentEnum horizontalAlignment, AguiVerticalAlignmentEnum verticalAlignment);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Function templates must be declared in the header file (unless you plan to only instantiate it for a for a specific set of parameters).  Therefore no need to export.

Comment: @Oil what about the AguiText namespace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need to export a namespace. From a compiled code perspective, namespaces are meaningless. You cannot reference them in code, they just define scope.

Namespaces wind up becoming part of class/function names during the name mangling process. They are not separate entities once a source file is compiled.

If you want to export the contents of a namespace, you need to export those entities, not the namespace itself.

Comment: Then where do I add AGUI_DECLSPEC so that the functions inside get exported, like drawTextArea?

Comment: do I do
AGUI_DECLSPEC void someThing();

Comment: Functions and classes are the actual entities being exported, so you would put your `__declspec` around those. Think of namespaces as little stickers you put on your functions. The stickers themselves don't define an entity, they just decorate other things. They do not define usable objects. They are just markup.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say "no need to export a namespace". It's not possible to export a namespace. `__declspec(dllexport/dllimport)` can only be applied at a type, function or variable declaration.

Comment: adding __declspec(dllexport) to the declaration in the .h solve the issue