# using a namespace accross DLLs / shared library

Tags: c++, dll, namespaces, shared-libraries

I'm writing a shared library/DLL with helper functions. So I declare namespaces to not get name clashes in the future. For classes this works fine, but I have some global functions that I also wanted to put in a namespace and this doesn't work. I get a linker error when I try to address the namespace. It looks as if a namespace can not be exported from inside a DLL.

I googled and found this thread here [Where should I put my DECLSPEC for a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200177/where-should-i-put-my-declspec-for-a-namespace) and I don't reall understand the answer. The point of the namespace is to seperate names and make them uniqely identifyable, so i wonder why it is an accepted answer saying that namspaces don't need to be exported. However, maybe I'm missing something here. I can see that a namespace on it's own can not be exported, but the functions inside should still belong the namespace and this seems to be not possible. However, the classes that I habve inside a namespace work as expected, so I'm a bit confused why this shouldn't apply to other symbols as well.

I ended now by creating a dummy class wrapper and declare my functions as static. It's not 100% like a namespace, but it similar enough for my purpose.

In the DLL:

```
class EXPORT_DECL Base64
{
   public:
       static std::string encode(unsigned char const *bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len);
       static std::string decode(std::string const &oBase64Encoded);
};
```

and in main I can address them like they were in the namespace.

```
Base64::encode(...);
```

I wanted to know though, if I'm missing something here and it is possible to use a namespace instead of using this workaround. And do shared libraries also have this restriction or is this only something from DLLs?

**update**

Shared library foo.h:

```
namespace mytest
{
     int mytestfkt(int a);
     EXPORT_DECL int decltest(int a);
}
```

shared library foo.cpp.

```
 int mytestfkt(int a)
 {
     return 0;
 }

int decltest(int a)
{
    return 0;
}
```

or this:

```
namespace mytest
{
 int mytestfkt(int a)
 {
     return 0;
 }

 EXPORT_DECL int decltest(int a)
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

or this:

```
int mytest::mytestfkt(int a)
{
 return 0;
}

EXPORT_DECL int mytest::decltest(int a)
{
return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int x = mytest::mytestfkt(1);
x = mytest::decltest(1);
```

result:

```
undefined reference to `mytest::mytestfkt(int)'
undefined reference to `mytest::decltest(int)'
```

Comment: Ugh, this is all windows-y! But I believe what the answer is saying is that you don't want to try and export the whole namespace. Export the functions that you want (that happen to live inside a namespace). Something like this `namespace N { int foo(); }` becomes something like `int N_foo();` after mangling, and then that name is exported. The namespace is a concept in your source code, not in the compiled DLL.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in using utility classes with static methods. Since you are doing C++ and not C this is the way to go as I would suggest. Having the same function in other namespaces is bad anyway from a code quality point of view as this may hide functions in other namespaces (un)-intentionally, making code hard to understand and more error prone

Comment: @BoBTFish, my point is that this doesn't work. When I use the namespace I get a linker error for undefined symbol for the function I try to call.

Comment: @Samuel, what you say makes sense, that's why I came up with this workaround. I still don't understand why this restrictions applies symblos only though. Also it wouldn't work for variables, because you can't make all of them static as this is quite a different concept. Well, if I need variables I would probablx use a class object anyway, so this is not a strong problem.

Comment: "this doesn't work" --- it does. Look at that little `std::` prefix. Does it work for standalone functions? Thought so. You are doing something wrong. I can't tell what exactly, because you are not showing what you are doing. Show your code, then perhaps we can figure it out together.

Comment: I updated with a sample

Comment: In `foo.h` you are declaring `mytest::decltest`, in `foo.cpp` you are defining `::decltest`. `mytest::decltest` is left undefined and the linker tells you that. This has nothing to do with DLLs and exports at all. You need to place your definitions in the .cpp file inside the namespace.

Comment: @n.m. I tried all possible combinations and I always get an error. Can you show me a working example?

Comment: Let's try again. You need to place your definitions in the .cpp file inside the namespace. Have you done that? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: As I said, I tried all all possible combinations and the error is always the same. Undefined linker symbol. See my update

Comment: How are you importing the functions in the consuming code? You may need the same namespace wrapping your `__declspec( dllimport )`s

Comment: I also tried this. Thats why I would like to see a working sample. I look at the std namespace and see if I can find out anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

What is `EXPORT_DECL`?  If you are including the same header file (the one shown in your q) in the library and user code then `EXPORT_DECL` has to expand differently depending on context.

In the library it has to map to `__declspec(dllexport)`, in the user code it has to expand to `__declspec(dllimport)`. Otherwise, you are telling the compiler to export the same symbol from both library and user code.  Since there's no definition for the `EXPORT_DECL`-tagged symbols in the user (correctly, since you want to import it from the library), you get a link-time error.

Typically this is done by having a conditional definition for `EXPORT_DECL`

```
#ifdef EXPORTING
#define EXPORT_DECL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT_DECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

then compile your library with `-DEXPORTING=1` and the user code with `-DEXPORTING=0`